# The "no-return-assign" - Difference between Assignment with and without Parentheses

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, return, eslint, parentheses

The [no-return-assign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign) allows no asignments in a return statement. But by default it allows it when you put your assignment in parentheses.

Is there a technical difference between `return (foo = 1 + 1)` and `return foo = 1 + 1`?

I have this question because I try the following with

```
return createMatrixRow(
  width,
  element,
  addWidth,
  elements.concat(addWidth ? Object.assign({}, element, (element.position.width = width)) : element)
)
```

To avoid the error message I put `element.position.width = width` in parentheses.

Comment: The grouping operator can change the order of evaluation, but it does never change the result of a single expression. I.e. `foo` and `(foo)` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No difference. In both cases, they form a single expression, except that with the parens, the expression is the grouping operator, which receives the original assignment expression and returns its result.

It's a fairly common trait of linters to use parens to manually override assignments that may look like errors.

For example, this will usually annoy the linter:

```
while (x = re.exec(data)) {
  // do work
}
```

The reason being that an assignment as a condition is very often a typo, where `==` was intended.

But this will often satisfy it:

```
while ((x = re.exec(data))) {
  // do work
}
```

The otherwise superfluous parents are a way of saying *"yes, I know this is an assignment, so I'll wrap it with these unnecessary parens to indicate that"*.

Answer (score 1):

The statements

```
return foo = 1 + 1;
```

and

```
return (foo = 1 + 1);
```

are identical as far as JavaScript semantics are concerned.